# IBM Watson Conversation how to add values in system entities

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

Hi I am using Watson Converstaion system entity @sys-date. Its working great. However I want some additional date things to be handled like 'End of quarter', 'Next month' etc. Is there anyway to enhance these system entities to identify additional values?

Comment: "Next Month" Should work by giving you the start and end date of the related month.

Comment: I am facing a problem like when i am using slots the responses is not coming to my android app but it's running fine in it's try it out section. what should i do?